# Having a P and Select tag on the same line

Tags: html, css

I want to have a `<p>` tag and `<select>` to be on the same line.

Everything I've tried so far hasn't worked. Below is what I currently have

```
<style type="text/css">
            #platformRating select,
            #platformRating p {
                display: inline;
                vertical-align: top;
                line-height: 28px;
            }
        </style>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">
        <div id="platformRating">
            <p>Platform:</p>
            <select id="cboPlatform" name="cboPlatform">
                <option>General</option>
                <option>Android</option>
                <option>Windows</option>
                <option>Web Service</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <textarea id="txtRatingDescription" name="txtRatingDescription" placeholder="Enter your comment here"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Obviously the style section is within the `<head>` of the document and the rest is in the `<body>`.

The `<p>platform</p>` and the `<select>` on the same line and then the text area is underneath, however, each element is on a new line which I don't want, so how would I resolve this?

### Update

I've found that @Nit's answer is correct except I have a small problem which I forgot about which is causing Nit's answer to not work.

In my stylesheet I have the following CSS for my `select` inputs.

```
select
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    appearance: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

The style above is for my whole site, however this select box I am trying to add I don't want to follow the rest of the site, I want it to be different. So this select styling to my stylesheet is causing it to not display on the same line. If I remove this, then its displayed on the same line. Can I add a class to this one select to make it work with this style that I want?

Comment: Put the `<select>` within the `<p>`?

Comment: As a sidenote; you're clearly using the `<p>` tag (paragraph) as a label.. there's a tag for that called `<label>` which would be more appropriate.. and it's inline by default too so no need to change it's display type

Comment: What is the problem? The code posted puts the `p` element on the same line as the `select` element. The markup is illogical, but that’s a different dimension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use inline displaying.

```css
#platformRating {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
  #platformRating select,
  #platformRating p {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 28px;
  }
</style>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">
  <div id="platformRating">
    <p>Platform:</p>
    <select id="cboPlatform" name="cboPlatform">
      <option>General</option>
      <option>Android</option>
      <option>Windows</option>
      <option>Web Service</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <textarea id="txtRatingDescription" name="txtRatingDescription" placeholder="Enter your comment here"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this has worked and I have changed my <p> tag to a label, always forget about that, but there is a problem with my stylesheet changing the select style across the site. I have updated my question with some more info on the problem

Comment: Sorted my stylesheet problem, I overrode the width as the stylesheet was set to 100% so it was being wrapped

Answer (score 1):

It would be more appropriate to use `<label>` tag for naming the select option. The `<p>` tag implicitly is displayed as `block`, so as suggested by Nit you can change that to `inline-block`.

Example for using `label`:

```
        <label for="cboPlatform">Platform:</label>
        <select id="cboPlatform" name="cboPlatform">
            <option>General</option>
            <option>Android</option>
            <option>Windows</option>
            <option>Web Service</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, use :`display : inline-block`
[Here is the difference between inline, block and inline block](http://dustwell.com/div-span-inline-block.html)